# El proposito de un objeto en POO es crearlo, utilizarlo para llenar una base de datos y luego destruirlo? en PHP que hago al cambiar de pagina

Tags: php, sql, poo, mvc

Entonces, si alguna vez lo necesitamos otra vez, lo tendremos que crear otra vez y rellenarlo con los datos de teníamos en la base de datos, lo utilizamos o lo modificamos, y lo destruimos otra vez?

Estoy estudiando PHP y con POO y patrón MVC.
Entiendo lo de las clases, tenemos una persona, que tiene piernas, brazos y cabeza, y además come, habla, duerme.
Hasta aquí bien.
En la primera vista, instanciamos una persona 1 y vemos una persona sin nada, hay una función de ponerle ropa, en el modelo, lo vestimos, y lo retornamos vestido al controlador para que nos lo enseñe en la vista.
Otra de darle de comer, en el modelo, le hacemos la comida, y la retornamos al controlador para que nos lo enseñe en una vista comiendo.
Al final del día lo destruimos? y que pasa si lo tengo que utilizar mas tarde, lo creo otra vez y lo recupero de la base de datos?
Eso es lo que no entiendo. porque mientras el código siga en la misma línea el objeto existe, pero al redireccionarte a otra pagina, todo desaparece. Tendría que hacer un include al principio de la nueva pagina de todo el programa anterior?
Gracias por anticipado

Comment: Hola. La mejor forma, de lejos, de contarnos todo esto, es con código. Que sea una pregunta de programación. Como está, estás describiendo código teórico que bien podría ser real. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: En PHP, lo que necesites conservar al navegar del lado del servidor suele dejarse en **sesión**. Así, un mismo usuario puede ver datos de una página a otra (como si está autenticado y esas cosas).

Comment: gracias por contestar tan rápido, solo he intentado explicar el recorrido de un objeto en un patrón MVC, nada en concreto, para que alguien me explique si me he pasado algo, ya que al pasar de programación estructurada y POO y además MVC, me exploto la cabeza, de verdad se me complico mucho entenderlo, y me gustaría que alguien me corrigiese si me equivoque en mi presentación. Asi que puedo guardar un objeto ya con todo seteado en una variable, y esta en una sesión? de verdad no me imaginaba que pudiese ser tan facil. muchas gracias a ti y a toda la comunidad

Comment: Estás mezclando conceptos de POO con detalles del funcionamiento de PHP. Primero se diseña y luego se implementa de acuerdo a lo que ofrezca el lenguaje. ENtonces, una cosa es que Persona tenga Brazos, Cabeza, Piernas y métodos comer, dormir, hablar, vestirse (que _suena razonable_ sin saber cómo lo implementarás)... otra muy diferente es cómo hago que no muera al navegar. En su formato actual es una presentación muy amplia que escapa al alcance del sitio

Comment: El concepto que te falta es [*Persistencia*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistencia_\(inform%C3%A1tica\)#Persistencia_de_objetos).

Comment: @Sal la contemple en mi respuesta.

Comment: Como bien dice @Sal, la *Persistencia* es el gran olvidado en tu pregunta. Las propiedades de `Persona` por lo general persisten (en una base de datos o en otra parte). En un contexto cualquiera tú puedes obtener los datos de una o más personas, guardarlos en instancias de la clase `Persona` para usarlos in situ, o más tarde (en cuyo caso podrías guardar las instancias ya creadas en una variable de sesión). Los datos en sí no se destruyen cuando terminas de trabajar, lo que se destruye es la instancia creada (si no la guardas), pues los datos **persisten** donde los tengas almacenados.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, te explico lo siguiente como introducción:

---

***POO:***

La programación orientada a objetos es un modelo de programación esta la puedes aplicar a cualquier lenguaje que la soporte. la principal idea de POO es simplificar el manejo de variables y correlacionar lógicamente las propiedades y caracterices que tenga una cosa.

***MVC:***

El Patrón de diseño Modelo Vista Controlador, Esto sirve para organizar tu código y separar las capas:

> *El Modelo:* Es la representación de la información con la cual el sistema opera, por lo tanto gestiona todos los accesos a dicha
> información, es la Lógica de Negocios.
>
> *El Controlador:* Responde a eventos (usualmente acciones del usuario) e invoca peticiones al 'modelo' cuando se hace alguna solicitud sobre
> la información
>
> *La Vista:* Presenta el 'modelo' (información y lógica de negocio) en un formato adecuado para interactuar (usualmente la interfaz de
> usuario)

*Diagrama MVC:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Persistencia de Datos:***

La persistencia de datos puede ser fácilmente confundida con la persistencia en memoria; incluso con la persistencia de aplicación.

La persistencia de datos consiste en la inicialización de objetos/variables con sus atributos predeterminados o atributos por defecto. Esto es posible con dos maneras de proceder.

1. Sobre un medio (de almacenamiento) fijo se guarda (cuando el objeto fue definido) un conjunto de datos que son recuperados cuando el tipo de objeto en cuestión es creado; dichos datos son transferidos a las propiedades del objeto.
2. Otro objeto mantiene los datos que serán transferidos a las propiedades del nuevo objeto creado. En este caso los datos están en memoria.

***Respuesta #1:***
 el como opera la Programación POO y el Diseño de MVC no esta relacionado a las funcionalidades que tenga tu Sitio Web, pero si a otras características como: escalabilidad, rendimiento, Optimización. implementar la persistencia de datos depende mas de tipo de implementación que quieras desarrollar o que requiera tu proyecto.

---

Después de esta breve y jugosa introducción atacaremos los distintos conceptos que puedes implementar.

***PHP:*** Este lenguaje tiene una particularidad y es que aunque la página web (el lado del cliente) esté abierto, no quiere decir que todas las variables que hayas declarado estén activas. O que te garantice que las variables no se perderán. PHP es un lenguaje interpretado y que en cada ejecución requiere crear las variables que vas a utilizar; excepto las de SESSION (estas son las únicas que suelen prevalecer a un refresh o cambio de pagina), entonces partiendo de esta característica la primera respuesta que te doy es:

***Respuesta #2:***
Si, PHP requiere que declares (crear) todas las variables/objetos, lectura de recursos (archivos) o lectura de base de datos, que vas a utilizar en tiempo de ejecución… a diferencia de otros lenguajes de programación orientada a escritorio que en ese caso puedes tener variables de entorno activas… esta característica no la tiene PHP; y aunque si tiene variables de entorno requiere crearlas en cada ejecución.

En el escenario que describes de hacer cambios de página existen 3 métodos para la permanencia de datos, tu eliges cual implementar:

***Implementación #1: Sesiones***
[Link sobre sesión (Manejo de Sesiones)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.session.php)

Las variables de Sesiones son las únicas que sobreviven a un refresh o cambio de pagina... en ellas puedes guardar los datos que tengas de tu muñequito; el problema es que normalmente las sesiones caducan, tienen un limite de almacenamiento si dependen de una cookie... etc.

para el tema del muñequito; al finalizar el día lo guardas en tu variable de sesión...

***Implementación #2: Archivo de Recursos***
[Link archivo JSon (Manejo de Recursos en formato json)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.json.php)

Otro método que puedes implementar es la permanencia de datos en archivos de recursos, normalmente se usan cuando necesitas interconectar sistema que no tiene ningún tipo de conectividad pero que pueden leer un archivo, por ejemplo en un archivo JSON puedes guardar el muñequito y sus propiedades ... esto te permite leerlo desde cualquier otro dispositivo o lenguaje que tenga o le hayas dado esa capacidad mediante la programación... existirá algunos problemas dependiendo del volumen de datos y la disponibilidad para la lectura y escritura del recurso o la búsqueda de datos relacionados en diferentes archivos.

También hay otros formatos de archivos de recursos como XMl, Yaml etc.. el principio es el mismo guardar en disco los datos que requieres compartir o leer después... se usa bastante para las configuraciones de aplicaciones.

***Implementación #3: Bases de Datos***
[Link sobre PDO (Manejo de Base de Datos)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php)

como dices puedes implementar Base de datos (te recomiendo usar PDO para manejarlas), esto te puede permitir crear múltiples muñecos... cuando lo recuperes de la base de datos debes tenerlo en el status en donde lo dejaste si fue que hiciste el guardado correctamente y no caducan como las sesiones, esto trae mejoras en temas de búsqueda de datos y relación de tablas como por ejemplo que pasa si el muñequito tiene casa y esa casa tambien es un objeto y tiene características y propiedades.

---

Este seria el concepto a aplicar para tu desarrollo, igualmente te exhorto a que crees un POST en donde coloques cualquier problema que tengas con tu Código  para poder apoyarte y cuando tengas 20 puntos podrás incluso participar del chat.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por la respuesta y los comentarios, me han ayudado a entender un poco mas este mundo de PHP, POO, y MVC.  y pensar que cuando empeze hace 40 años con mi spectrum 48K solo tenia que saber BASIC, ahora es como tener la torre de babel cada vez son mas lenguajes y mas paradigmas y mas  patrones, pero me gusta que le voy a hacer a ms 50 años. Un saludo desde Las Palmas de Gran Canaria

Comment: @JavierMonleón no te preocupes un saludo desde la Ciudad de Panamá.

Comment: @JavierMonleón te invito al chat de SE en español hay podemos darte un poco mas de apoyo: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol